# Free baggage allowance: Weight concept vs Piece concept?

Tags: commercial-aviation, weight

What are the advantages of piece concept free baggage allowance policy compared to the weight concept free baggage allowance policy in terms of contribution to the profitability of a commercial airline?

Which policy provides more load space in the cargo holds of a passenger aircraft and/or provides more payload to carry compared to the other or vica versa.

Comment: This question would be better answered on [travel.SE](https://travel.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: It also sounds like it may be a homework question

Answer (score 1):

There are more rules involved here and the Airline can make a judgement call here which ever is more suitable for them.
Here at EHAM we have a limit that one person is only allowed to lift a bag of 23kg, if a bag is heavier it needs to be lifted by two persons thus increasing the processing cost for the airline. For aircraft the most important parameter is weight, more weight equals more fuel or, in extreme cases, less range. (range is traded for added payload)
So depending on the load factors of the aircraft and the amount of additional cargo the airline transports it can determine if it has the space available to transport more voluminous luggage by allowing multiple pieces that add up to 23kg per pax for example.

So there is no definitive answer possible to your question as there is a trade off to be made by the airline, filling the entire cargo hold with a high density material like lead is not possible, the aircraft would be too heavy.

Comment: *"we have a limit that one person is only allowed to lift a bag of 23kg"* I know that a lot of airlines have similar "rules", but I've yet to see a baggage handler ask for assistance in moving any luggage, even the ones very clearly marked "HEAVY".